# I have an issue with the website after moving files to sub domain

Tags: php, subdomain

Hi Guys I would really appreciate your help for this issue. Can you tell me what are the possible problems and ways to solve them on this kind of issue.

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcooX.png)

Thank you so much for those who will answer.

Comment: Your server is mis-configured... there are **way** too many possible reasons for any kind of definitive answer.

Comment: We will need a lot more information on how you transferred your files and your site. Was it working before?

Comment: Hi! I opened the error logs and this is what I got "2016-06-20 16:18:05 Error 112.198.75.24 500 GET /shop.php HTTP/1.1  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36 347  Apache access"

Comment: Although I can access the subdomain but all pages that needs connection to database are displaying like that.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Error 500 Internal server error

Introduction
The Web server (running the Web Site) encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request by the client (e.g. your Web browser or our CheckUpDown robot) for access to the requested URL.

This is a 'catch-all' error generated by the Web server. Basically something has gone wrong, but the server can not be more specific about the error condition in its response to the client. In addition to the 500 error notified back to the client, the Web server should generate some kind of internal error log which gives more details of what went wrong. It is up to the operators of the Web server site to locate and analyse these logs.

Fixing 500 errors - general
This error can only be resolved by fixes to the Web server software. It is not a client-side problem. It is up to the operators of the Web server site to locate and analyse the logs which should give further information about the error.